# Can you write a trigger on a view that utilizes data from the insert and delete tables after a change to its base tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, triggers, view

I'm not sure the wording of my question fully illustrates the issue, so I will elaborate as best as I can.

We are trying to synchronize changes in one MS SQL database to another MS SQL database, and the solution prescribed at this point involves a series of triggers that will take the inserted, or updated information and will send this row of data via dbmail to an inbox on the receiving server. A small mail parser reviews the letters and extracts the pertinent data and populates the receiving database.

The issue I'm working out now is how to send not only the inserted data but also, in the case of an update statement, both the updated and the unchanged data so that a complete row will always be issued to the mail parser. Whats more, there are only so many fields we are working with as the other fields are deemed classified. The information we will be accessing will come from at least two, but no more than five different base tables.

Will triggers written on the view have access to the insert and delete logical tables created in the case of a change in a base table, or is the view blind to such activity. If so how do I pull together a complete row if the data is coming from three or four tables?

There was no issue getting rows and sending/parsing the data when the tests were triggering from a single table, but triggers on the view do not function the same (appparently) and the script produces no results as the changes are not occuring against the view. The idea that is growing in the back of my mind is to write triggers in the base tables that react to updates/inserts and then use those triggers to launch the view trigger utilzing the data from the ins and del logic tables.

Will this work? Is this insane or plausible?

Answer (score 0):

Please forgive me if I am wrong.
Use the "instead of trigger" in the view. Write the logic for the base tables in this trigger.

Comment: The 'instead of' trigger is an option I had experimented with, and would work to suit my needs were the circumstances different. I've actually managed to avoid this complication entirely just joining the inserted table to the other tables in question inside the trigger and passing a complete row to the dbmail sproc each time, while carefully managing the duplicate checking in the application layer. As with most things, there was a much simpler way (although I admit my explanation doesn't make it sound any simpler). Thank you again for your answer, and your attention regarding my inquiry.